# Converting raw packets to pcap format and appending to a pcap file

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, libpcap

I am reading the raw packet data and converting it to Pcap format (have a function for this). I have a list of raw packets (in list format) and I need to read each packet and append it to a pcap file in the pcap format only. I tried using mergecap but it doesn't work. So I tried another thing `tail -c +25 file2.pcap >> file1.pcap` and it works.

I convert a packet[0] to pcap, store it in a pcap file using the below code, then do similar thing for the remaining packets, and keep on appending the pcap files using the tail command. But it's just an overhead (as I have 10^6 packets).

Here's what I did -

```
class Pcap:

   def __init__( self, filename, link_type=PCAP_DATA_LINK_TYPE ):
      self.pcap_file = open( filename, 'wb' )
      self.pcap_file.write( struct.pack( '@ I H H i I I I ',
                            PCAP_MAGICAL_NUMBER, PCAP_MJ_VERN_NUMBER,
                            PCAP_MI_VERN_NUMBER, PCAP_LOCAL_CORECTIN,
                            PCAP_ACCUR_TIMSTAMP, PCAP_MAX_LENGTH_CAP, link_type ) )

   def writelist( self, data ):
      for i in data:
         self.write( i )
      return

   def write( self, data ):
      ts_sec, ts_usec = map( int, str( time.time() ).split( '.' ) )
      length = len( data )
      self.pcap_file.write( struct.pack( '@ I I I I', ts_sec,
                                         ts_usec, length, length ) )
      self.pcap_file.write( data )

   def close(self):
      self.pcap_file.close()


class try:
   def start(self, packets):
      p = Pcap( "PcapData.pcap" )
      p.write( str( packets[0] ) )
      p.pcap_file.flush()
      for packet in packets[1:]:
         p = Pcap( "temp.pcap" )
         p.write( str( packet ) )
         p.pcap_file.flush()
         p.close()
         os.system( "tail -c +25 temp.pcap >> PcapData.pcap" )
      p.close()
```

I tried using text2pcap too, for the conversion but that doesn't work in my case. Same for the mergecap.

Comment: Could you show your current code for a single packet?

Comment: @pchaigno Edited the question description. :)

Comment: You'll need to add it into your OP. Nobody is going to browse to some random website to retrieve the code ;)

Comment: @pchaigno Really sorry about that. Have made the changes. Will edit it again if required.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct, specially on the start method, check this comments

```
def start(self, packets):
  p = Pcap( "PcapData.pcap" )
  p.write( str( packets[0] ) )
  p.pcap_file.flush()
  for packet in packets[1:]:
     # You create a pcap file with one packet
     p = Pcap( "temp.pcap" )
     p.write( str( packet ) )
     p.pcap_file.flush()
     p.close()
     # this os.system is wrong, you can not merge pcap files like that
     # you are appending the header file also, use mergepcap
     os.system( "tail -c +25 temp.pcap >> PcapData.pcap" )
  p.close()
```

here is a proposed solution

```
def start(self, packets):
  p = Pcap( "PcapData.pcap" )
  p.write( str( packets[0] ) )
  p.pcap_file.flush()
  for packet in packets[1:]:
     p.write( str( packet ) )
  p.pcap_file.flush()
  p.close()
```